# XQuartz error on ssh connection

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, imagemagick, xquartz

I'm connected to a remote Linux server via ssh, and I'm trying to execute ImageMagick's `display` command. I know that the problem is probably not on the server side, because when I connect from different machines I don't get the same problem. And I installed XQuartz on my local machine as well as connected using the ssh tags -Y and -X (neither fix the problem) and I'm still getting the following error. My computer is a MacBook Pro running El Capitan. Any idea?

```
display: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/426.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is to start **XQuartz** in the background on your Mac before you do anything and allow remote machines to connect.

So, on your Mac, in Terminal, start **XQuartz**:

```
X &
```

Now right-click the **XQuartz** icon in your Dock and click:

```
Applications -> Terminal
```

and in the Terminal that appears, type:

```
xhost +
```

Later, when you have it working, tighten up the security on the `xhost` command by being a bit more specific with IP addresses.

Comment: Unforunately, I get the same problem here. When I type in "xhost +" I get

Comment: xhost:  unable to open display ""

Comment: And when I try to call the display command, I get the same error as above